# How do I get the filter to work from other pages?

Tags: javascript, filter, gallery

I have a project filter which runs and displays selected images when the category is clicked..

Is it possible to create a URL which links to the pre-filtered image gallery?

```
onclick="filterSelection('home')"
```

For example the filter to open the selected category when linking from the contact page.

Here is the code..

```
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}


// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

The page in progress is here https://www.mgtdevelopments.ie/mgt-developments-projects.htm

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with 'external pages'? Could you explain a bit more what you want to achieve?

Comment: How would I get the filtered selection working from the contact page for example as the code below doesn't work...  `<a href="mgt-developments-projects.htm" onclick="filterSelection('home')">Home Extensions</a>`